# How can I load csv file made of irregular, mixed formats of data, and mixed delimiters into the dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I tried so many methods recommended by other threads, but failed to make my code work.

So... I want to load the csv file arranged like below to the dataframe.

```
year, 2021
month, march
date, 28
here, are, values
42.1, 28.7, 27.0, 9.54, 12.23, 22.25
```

I had a hard time dealing with this csv file(actually this is just a concise example of mine) because of the irregularity, letters and numbers-mixed formats and comma and space-mixed delimiters of this data.

I want this dataset to be placed left-aligned in the dataframe like,

```
year  2021  NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN
month march NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN
date  28    NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN
here  are   values NaN  NaN   NaN
42.1  28.7  27.0   9.54 12.23 22.25
```

Sorry that I cannot show you what I have done so far, because I have a bunch of versions of code from the methods I searched.

Answer (score 0):

If all `values` refer to the same `year`, `month` and `date`, you need to have a DataFrame where each line is an observation of `value`, i.e.

```
year = 2021
month = 'march'
date = 28
values = [42.1, 28.7, 27.0, 9.54, 12.23, 22.25]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': np.repeat(year, len(values)),
    'month': np.repeat(month, len(values)),
    'date': np.repeat(date, len(values)),
    'value': values
})
```

yielding

```
   year  month  date  value
0  2021  march    28  42.10
1  2021  march    28  28.70
2  2021  march    28  27.00
3  2021  march    28   9.54
4  2021  march    28  12.23
5  2021  march    28  22.25
```

If you want it transposed, you can do

```
df = df.T
```

that gives

```
           0      1      2      3      4      5
year    2021   2021   2021   2021   2021   2021
month  march  march  march  march  march  march
date      28     28     28     28     28     28
value   42.1   28.7   27.0   9.54  12.23  22.25
```

Comment: yeah I also think this looks better... but I need the result like what I described up there. No header or index. I edited the result I need more clearly!

Comment: From my `df` simply do `df.T` to transpose it